# Why can't I see any Graphics when I run my code?

Tags: visual-studio

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Pen green = new Pen(Color.Green);

        System.Drawing.SolidBrush fillRed = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush fillYellow = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
          e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(red, 0, 0, 220, 90);
          e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(green, 0, 0, 220, 90);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Add context to your question, what error are you getting? which env are you running your code? what is the expected output?

Comment: The issue I am having is when I run this in Visual Studio, no graphics show in the window I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code you uploaded does not contains the line which add Form1_Paint method to this.Paint event, or invoking that method directly. I think maybe Form1_Paint was not executed at the very beginning, cause the graphic was loaded correctly when I did

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
    this.Invalidate(); /// this fires Paint event
}
```

on my environment.